# Cake PHP Exception error

Tags: cakephp, exception, error-handling

I am getting these repeated errors and I can't figure it out.

```
PHP Fatal error:  [CakeException] Unknown status code
#0 /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(215): CakeResponse-    >statusCode(2)
#1 [internal function]: ExceptionRenderer->error400(Object(SocketException))
#2 /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php(178): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(122): ExceptionRenderer->render()
#4 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(SocketException))
#5 {main} in /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php on line 131
```

These errors are always followed by this error, but I don't know if it's related. I have removed trailing and leading whitespaces from all files in use.

```
[31-Mar-2014 16:25:38 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php:534) in /home/gourmet/public_html/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php on line 444
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21501308/825364

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here. It covers the error cause.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24993756/825364

In your case, status code 2 is not a valid HTTP Status code. Additionally, the Cannot Modify header info code occurs because you are outputting data to the response before everything is complete.

Basically, your server starts a response, for example a 200 OK response. Then half way through there is an error and it tries to send a header of 500 Internal Server Error, but some headers have already been sent.

If you want to set your own HTTP Status codes, you can use the following in the controller:
http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeResponse.html#_httpCodes

I personally place this in AppController.